# In Shopify, am i able to change the display of variants title?

Tags: shopify, liquid

my variants title is “pack/4 bottles:4/PK”
“4/PK” is needed for shipping company to catch specific item.
However, it looks ugly when "4/PK" is displayed on page
Is there a way to hide it? Which liquid template should i touch? 
Should I use

```
    {{variant.title|move:'4/PK'}}
```

where should i put this code?

Answer (score 1):

While this sounds more like something that should be assigned as an option for your variants instead of in the title, you can hide the part of the variants title that you don't want via using `split` and `first`

https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#split

split can be used to split a string (in this case your variant.title) into an array based on a set delimiter to divide it.

So you could do something only the lines of

```
{{variant.title | split: ':' | first }}
```

In your case, the output of the above would be: `pack/4 bottles`.

As for which liquid templates you will need to edit this into ... it will depend on your store. However some common areas would be:

- product.liquid
- cart.liquid

I highly recommend you read the the shopify liquid documents [Here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid)

Also, make sure to make [a backup theme](https://help.shopify.com/manual/using-themes/theme-files#duplicate-themes)  before doing any liquid changes in your theme that you are unsure of.

Hope this helps!